# Django Sales Page with Dynamic Customer and Product Data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm attempting to create a simple sales form using Django where customer data is displayed at the top of the page, followed by another form below it that allows users to add products. At the bottom, I want to show the total order amount and other calculated details. Essentially, I'm trying to create a product form nested within a sales form, involving data from various other models.

I've made several attempts but haven't been able to find similar solutions in forums and tutorials. Could someone provide guidance or ideias on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.